# Generate object with data from csv efficiently in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, class

I have a .csv file with node information (including node_id, x, y), and I try to generate object for each record in .csv file. Now I'm using apply method, but it take almost same running time compared with for loop (1 min). How can I do this efficiently (less running time) since .csv file contains huge number of records.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        self.node_id = 0
        self.x = 0.0
        self.y = 0.0

    def load_data(x):
        node = Node()
        node.node_id = x['node_id']
        node.x = x['x']
        node.y = x['y']
        return node

if "__main__" == __name__:
    time1 = datetime.datetime.now()
    node_info = pd.read_csv('input_node.csv', header = 0)
    node_series = node_info.apply(Node.load_data,axis=1)
    node_list = list(node_series.values)
    time2 = datetime.datetime.now()
    time_delta = time2 - time1
```

[image: .csv file sample]

Comment: Why are you trying to generate an object for each row in your dataframe?

Comment: @rahlf23 This is just a small part of my program, and we have node class, link class and network class, so object oriented program may be helpful to organize all things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some tests and you'll be better off building your nodes while reading csv rows:

```
import csv

class Node:
    def __init__(self, node_id, x, y):
        self.node_id = node_id
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

with open('input_node.csv') as fin:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    header = next(reader)  # read header
    node_list = [Node(*row) for row in reader]
```

This should be way faster than your current implementation

Comment: It does work using your code! May I ask what's the function of 'header = next(reader)', since it seems not be used in this code.

Comment: `reader` is a generator, and the first row it generates is the header `node_id,x,y`, which we wanna skip. So `next(reader)` just gets the next value from the generator

Comment: If that solves your issue, please be sure to accept my answer as the correct one. Me love dose sweet rep points

Comment: amazing! got it now.